# Как входящие значения привязать к индексам массива?

Tags: java, массивы

На вход программы  с консоли поступают буквенные значения. Их нужно перевести  в цифры, при условии что а = 0. Сколько на вход поступает букв столько в итоге должно быть и цифр.
Вот моя реализация, но при вводе данных происходит переполнение массива. Что я делаю не так? И как это правильно сделать?

```
//Вывести зашифрованное в буквах числовое значение. Где а = 0

public class TransformingStringToNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Введите буквенное значение");
        String inputCharacters = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(toTransform(inputCharacters));
    }

    public static StringBuilder toTransform(String inputCharacters) {
        //char [] exampleArray = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','j','h','i','g'};
        CharSequence a = "a";
        CharSequence b = "b";
        CharSequence c = "c";
        CharSequence d = "d";
        CharSequence e = "e";
        CharSequence f = "f";
        CharSequence j = "j";
        CharSequence h = "h";
        CharSequence i = "i";
        CharSequence g = "g";
        int index = 0;
        char[] charArray = inputCharacters.toCharArray();
        char [] result = new char[charArray.length];
        for (; index < charArray.length; index++) {
            if(inputCharacters.contains(a)) {
                result[0] = '0';
            }else if (inputCharacters.contains(b)){
                result[1] = '1';
            }else  if(inputCharacters.contains(c)){
                result[2] = '2';
            }else  if (inputCharacters.contains(d)){
                result[3] = '3';
            }else if(inputCharacters.contains(e)){
                result[4] = '4';
            }else if (inputCharacters.contains(f)){
                result[5] = '5';
            }else if(inputCharacters.contains(j)){
                result[6] = '6';
            }else if (inputCharacters.contains(h)){
                result[7] = '7';
            }else if (inputCharacters.contains(i)){
                result[8] = '8';
            }else if (inputCharacters.contains(g)){
                result[9] = '9';
            }

        }

        return new StringBuilder().append(result[index]);
    }

}
```

Comment: `for (int index = 0; index < charArray.length -1;... ` <- индексы пробегают от 0 до length -1, то есть всего length элементов

Comment: Отнимите от численного значения символа (`(int) charArray[i]`) численное значение 'a'

Comment: @MBo,  имеется ввиду в StringBuilder?

Comment: Вы понимаете логику, что для получения цифр, соответствующим буквам, достаточно выполнить   `d = (char) ((int)c - (int)'a' + (int)'0')` ?

Comment: @MBo, вот честно, не совсем. не могли бы разъяснить? здесь вы просто отнимаете символы и остаются индексы (числа)?

Comment: Буква 'a' имеет код 97, буква 'b' - код 98 и так далее. Цифра '0' - 48,  '1' = 49 и т.д. Далее простая арифметика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TransformingStringToNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Введите буквенное значение");
        String inputCharacters = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(toTransform(inputCharacters));
    }

    public static StringBuilder toTransform(String inputCharacters) {
        int CHAR_A = 97;
        char[] charArray = inputCharacters.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (char value : charArray) {
            stringBuilder.append(value - CHAR_A);
            inputCharacters = inputCharacters.substring(1);
        }
        return stringBuilder;
    }
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: @Delembech, укоротил слегка. Если считаете ответ верным - отметьте как принятый

Comment: как это сделать?)

Comment: @Delembech слева есть кнопка - отметить как принятый

Comment: хотел еще уточнить что в данном случае значит вот эта строка ?
int CHAR_A = 97;

Comment: @Delembech char 'a' приведенный к int равен 97. Исходя из того что 'а' равно нулю строится логика нумерации остальных букв.

Comment: Да, уже увидел таблицу ASCII. В любом случае спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если судить по-коду и исправить некоторые ошибки, то ваш код можно существенно сократить (думаю, даже больше, поскольку я не большой знаток Java):

```
String inputCharacters = "<Строка на вход>";

// Символьная последовательность, можно сказать маска
CharSequence maskSeq = "abcdefjhig";

// массив сигналов, что символ из маски найден во входной строке
char[] result = new char[str.length()];

// Бежим по символам маски
for(int i = 0; i < maskSeq.length() -1; i++) {
    // Если входная строка содержит необходимый символ, то
    // в соответствующую позицию 
    if( inputCharacters.contains(String.valueOf(charSeq.charAt(i))) )
        result[i] = (char)i;
}
```

Comment: если использовать все символы в последовательности то так не сработает. я пробовал. хотя, возможно и не правильно пробовал